# How to deploy local files without commiting to git?

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I'm working in local branch and want to try my changes on staging server, but I don't want to commit these changes. Can I commit local changes.

I know about deploy:upload recipe. I need a way to deploy several files or whole working derictory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important of capistrano is to allow execute code on remote server, what we call deploy is a set of default scripts that do a lot of small tasks required for setting up new version of application on server.

### So it is possible to write your own scrip that will execute following script (it's not working probably):

## pack sources

system "tar -czf /tmp/package.tgz *"

## upload it to server

upload "/tmp/package.tgz" "/tmp/package.tgz"

## remove old files, unpack sources on server

run "cd /app_path/; rm -rf *; tar -xzf /tmp/package.tgz"

## override (force recursively symlinks) files with some server configs ... like database.yml

run "cp -flrs /app_shared_path/* /app_path/"

## restart application - this is for passenger, use your own server command for restart

### run "cd /app_path/; touch tmp/restart.txt"

I did similar setup once for deployment - before I got access to git.

Answer (score 0):

I deploy some cached (minified, etc) javascript files from a rails app. The simplest way is just to do this in a capestrano task:

```
top.upload("public/javascripts/cache", "#{current_path}/public/javascripts/cache")
```

This will use `scp` to upload the entire 'cache' directory.